# Condition expression in a PutItem request is not supported by DynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-java-sdk-2.x

I am trying to conditionally write an item to a DynamoDB table.

I am using [AWS SDK for Java 2.x](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html). Below is my code:

```java
PutItemEnhancedRequest<AssessmentBean> putItemRequest =
    PutItemEnhancedRequest.builder(AssessmentBean.class)
        .conditionExpression(sqsMsgIdNoMatch)
        .item(assessment)
        .build();
WriteBatch batch =
    WriteBatch.builder(AssessmentBean.class)
        .addPutItem(putItemRequest)
        .mappedTableResource(table)
        .build(); // This line throws the IllegalArgumentException
BatchWriteItemEnhancedRequest batchWriteRequest =
    BatchWriteItemEnhancedRequest.builder().addWriteBatch(batch).build();

eDDBClient
    .batchWriteItem(batchWriteRequest)
    .whenCompleteAsync(/* not important to this question */);
```

As indicated by the comment in the code above, my code throws an `IllegalArgumentException`:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A mapper extension inserted a conditionExpression in a PutItem request as part of a BatchWriteItemRequest. This is not supported by DynamoDb. An extension known to do this is the VersionedRecordExtension which is loaded by default unless overridden. To fix this use a table schema that does not have a versioned attribute in it or do not load the offending extension.

Below is some type information:

- `putItemRequest` is a `software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.model.PutItemEnhancedRequest` object
- `batch` is a `software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.model.WriteBatch` object
- `batchWriteRequest` is a `software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.model.BatchWriteItemEnhancedRequest` object
- `eDDBClient` is a `software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.DynamoDbEnhancedAsyncClient` object

How do correctly conditionally write an item to DynamoDB?

Comment: You cannot specify conditions on individual put and delete requests with [BatchWriteItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html). You would have to use individual PutItem request(s).

Comment: Right that makes sense, as it wouldn't make sense to write multiple items in a batch, where each item in the batch has a different condition. At least, that is how I understand it, please correct me if I am wrong.